# Oracle return the first row, not returning the first row

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I have this query :

```
select (quarter_1 + quarter_2 + quarter_3 + quarter_4) as total 
from budget where as_of_dt < to_date('2016-06-28', 'yyyy-MM-dd') 
order by as_of_dt desc;
```

Which returns bunch of numbers such as :

[image]

My requirement is to always capture the first number, so when I try to do that :

```
select * from (
  select (quarter_1 + quarter_2 + quarter_3 + quarter_4) as total 
  from budget where as_of_dt < to_date('2016-05-16', 'yyyy-MM-dd') 
  order by as_of_dt desc
) WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

I get this result :

[image]

Which is why I m puzzled about this, why is that I m getting the second row instead of the first one? What am I doing wrong here?

**Update including as_of_dt in result for first query:**

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the output of the 1st query, including the `as_of_dt` column? They two rows may have the same exact date.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ please see my update

Comment: May want to to_char the as_of_dt column to see the time?

Comment: Something else that doesn't look quite right, you have `< to_date('2016-05-16', 'yyyy-MM-dd')` but are getting values greater than that date?

Comment: @NickS nice catch! (although we are not yet sure if all the dates are June-2016 or June 16th ;)

Comment: Gandalf updated the 1st query to have `'2016-06-28'`. I guessed he forgot to do the same in the 2nd query.

Comment: @NickS you were right I didn't edit the first query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is right there, in the data.  (I assume that the time part is `00:00:00` in all of them):

The `order by` has ties. There is not one "first row" but 3 of them.

So, when the 2nd query restricts the result to one row, one of the 3 is - arbitrarily - chosen. It may not be the same row chosen the next time you run the same query!